# Related many to one navigation properties not loading with EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am struggling to get some related navigation properties loading up using EF code first.

I have a User table which is my primary table, which every time you update it, it generates a UserLight object containing only the basics. This is linked via a one-to-one mapping with User, so the User object generates the identity key and then when it saves, a UserLlight object is created using that UserId as it's key.

I now have a conversation object between two users which I want to load in only the UserLight objects for the sender and receiver, for performance reasons. I have tried mapping using Fluent and CF but when I load the objects from my repository, only the UserStartedId and UserRecipientId integer fields are populated, the actual UserLight objects UserStarted and UserRecipient are null.

My conversation class is as follows

```
public class DbConversation 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ConversationId { get; set; }

    public virtual DbUserLight UserStarted { get; set; }
    public int UserStartedId { get; set; }

    public virtual DbUserLight UserRecipient { get; set; }
    public int UserRecipientId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<DbStoryMessage> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

My Userlight class is as follows (abbreviated)

```
public class DbUserLight 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext OnModelCreating has the following

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DbUserLight>()
    .HasKey(a => a.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<DbUserLight>()
    .Property(a => a.UserId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

modelBuilder.Entity<DbStoryConversation>()
    .HasKey(c => c.ConversationId);
modelBuilder.Entity<DbStoryConversation>()
    .Property(c => c.ConversationId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<DbStoryConversation>()
    .HasMany<DbStoryMessage>(c => c.Messages)
    .WithRequired(m => m.Conversation)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

And my repository call is as follows

```
public IQueryable<DbStoryInboxMessage> GetInboxMessages()
{
    return Work.Context.StoryInboxMessages
        .Include(i => i.Conversation.UserStarted)
        .Include(i => i.Conversation.UserRecipient)
        .Include(i => i.Conversation.Messages);
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on why this is not working?

Comment: this is a web or desktop application ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the foreign key annotations?

```
    public class DbConversation 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ConversationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserStartedId")]
    public virtual DbUserLight UserStarted { get; set; }
    public int UserStartedId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserRecipientId")]
    public virtual DbUserLight UserRecipient { get; set; }
    public int UserRecipientId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<DbStoryMessage> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This probably helps, but could you concede to the OP's style by showing the fluent version?